# How can I measure amount of ozone byproduct coming out of hydroxyl generator

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ozone

A Hydroxyl generator releases hydroxyl radicals into the air to neutralize odors and kill mold.

Most hydroxyl generators also release some amount of ozone as a byproduct. How much ozone is released varies from one hydroxyl generator to the next.

Hydroxyl is supposed to be safe to use in occupied premises. Large amounts of ozone are not.

How can I measure the amount of ozone released by my hydroxyl generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ozone is very reactive, so unless you have an industrial scale hydroxyl generator, the ozone will readily react with organic matter in the air and surrounding surfaces before it builds up to dangerous levels. There are commercial portable instruments that are sold to monitor ozone concentration, they will be in the \$500 to $1500 price range for the instrument. You can also look at this [simple experimental apparatus](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ed082p282) described in the Journal of Chemical Education for a cheaper alternative.

Comment: Thank you, J. I am not looking for a lot of precision, so the cheap, high-school experiment set up should do it for me.